# What is this flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

This flower is growing in my back yard out of the wall. I've tried Googling "purple flower yellow center" and similar terms but I can't find an exact match.

[image: wide picture]
[image: closer picture]

I'm in North-East England if that's any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Kenilworth Ivy,

[image]

or, scientifically, Cymbalaria muralis. It loves to climb on walls and brickwork ("muralis" signifying "wall" in Latin). I did not know until now that it is considered (by [some](http://www.naturalmedicinalherbs.net/herbs/c/cymbalaria-muralis=kenilworth-ivy.php)) to be medicinal.

Comment: Thank you! A precise match, do you know if it's detrimental to the walls or is it fine growing there to its own content?

Comment: @Nemon , I don't know, but it is very delicate and easy to rip out. The stems never seem to get very thick to the point where they would widen existing cracks. Nor does it grab onto surfaces leaving unsightly tracks with those ugly sucker-feet like regular ivy does. I think it's pretty, so I *hope* it's not destroying my house.

Comment: Right for the identification and for the comment. Very weak roots, and it will growth not dense (Erigeron has more problem because it allow nests and it pull birds and insects.

Comment: So successful it is now considered invasive in Canada, USA, Australia and New Zealand see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cymbalaria_muralis